# form_for models with specific relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have
Models

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_artists
  has_many :singers, -> { where role: "Singer" }, class_name: "GroupArtist"
  has_many :guitarists, -> { where role: "Guitarist" }, class_name: "GroupArtist"
end

class GroupArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_artists
  has_many :groups, through: :group_artists
end
```

group_artists table has these columns

```
class CreateGroupArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :group_artists, id: false do |t|
      t.references :group, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :artist, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.string :role
      t.string :acting

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @group = Group.new

    @singers = @group.singers.build
    @guitarists = @group.guitarists.build

    @artists = Artist.all // for a selection
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.new(allowed_params)
    @group.save
  end

  private

  def allowed_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, :singers, :guitarists, group_artists_attributes: [:group_id, :artist_id, :role, :acting])
  end
end
```

views/groups/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Singers" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :singers do |singer| %>
    <%= singer.select(:artist_id, @artists.collect { |a| [a.name, a.id.to_i] }, { include_blank: true }) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label "Guitarists" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :guitarists do |guitarist| %>
    <%= guitarist.select(:artist_id, @artists.collect { |a| [a.name, a.id.to_i] }, { include_blank: true }) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

It creates the group all right, but doesn't create the relation in GroupArtist. 
I know something's missing in the controller part. I should add something after the ".build" like (role: "Singer") but it doesn't do anything as well.

Ruby -v 2.4.1
Rails -v 5.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These were the adds and changes I needed to make it work.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_artists
  has_many :singers, -> { where role: "Singer" }, class_name: "GroupArtist"
  has_many :guitarists, -> { where role: "Guitarist" }, class_name: "GroupArtist"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_artists, 
     reject_if: proc { |a| a[:artist_id].blank? || a[:role].blank? },
     allow_destroy: true
end

class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @group = Group.new
    @group.group_artists.build
    @artists = Artist.all // for a selection
  end
  def create
    @group = Group.new(allowed_params)
    @group.save
  end
end
```

groups/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>

  <div class="singers">
    <%= f.label :singers %>
    <%= f.fields_for :group_artists do |ga| %>
      <%= ga.collection_select :artist_id, Artist.all, :id, :name %>
      <%= ga.hidden_field :role, value: 'Singer' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="guitarists">
    <%= f.label :guitarists %>
    <%= f.fields_for :group_artists do |ga| %>
      <%= ga.collection_select :artist_id, Artist.all, :id, :name %>
      <%= ga.hidden_field :role, value: 'Guitarist' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

That way you don't have to specify the artist's role if his name's selected in the singers or guitarists labeled div.
That's it. Thanks to [max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46255533/1748610), for guiding me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `group_artists` as more than just a simple join table you need to use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to create a row with metadata:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_artists
  has_many :singers, -> { where role: "Singer" }, class_name: "GroupArtist"
  has_many :guitarists, -> { where role: "Guitarist" }, class_name: "GroupArtist"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_artists, 
     reject_if: ->{|a| a[:artist_id].blank? || a[:role].blank?}
end
```

Also the structure using different associations to create nested records based on the role of the band members is not really scalable - for every possible role the class / form will swell.

Instead you may want to use two selects:

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
  <fields_for :group_artists do |ga| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :artist_id, "Artist" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :artist_id, Artist.all, :id, :name %>
      <%= f.label :role %>
      <%= f.select :role, %w[ Singer Guitarist ] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Also you are not saving the record in your `#create` method.

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(allowed_params)
  if @group.save 
    # ...
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I was about to try your stuff out, but at the views point, is there any other way to make it like I don't have to choose for the role?
Like it's section dependent. If I have a :role section in my form, whatever choices made in that section will automatically apply role: "Singer" (for example).

Comment: Your answer was good but missed one detail, I edited it, and now it fully works. Just need to figure out some other stuffs now, unrelated to this question.  
Thank you, again. Your 'views' part made me realize the issue I actually had was in group#new. Nothing told to GroupArtists to add a new entry, hence why it never created an entry. I'll accept your answer once you accept the edits.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in your controller action create

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(allowed_params)
  @group.save
end
```

Group.new doesn't persist model in DB but save after yes.

Comment: Sorry, I had it but skipped it here, no idea why. My bad.